# When is a value function twice differentiable?

Tags: optimization, real-analysis

Consider the optimization problem
$$
V(\gamma) \ \equiv \ \max_x \ f(x,\gamma) \quad \text{s.t.} \quad g(x,\gamma) \leq 0
$$

Roughly, the Benveniste-Scheinkman theorem implies that if $f$ and $g$ are smooth enough and if $f$ is concave and $g$ is convex, then $V$ is differentiable.

Are there assumptions on $f$ and $g$ that ensure $V$ is twice differentiable?

Comment: The title is about the policy function, but the question in the body is about the value function. Could you clarify?

Comment: Sorry for the typo and thank you for clarifying. I updated the title. I am interested in the value function.

Comment: This might be relevant: [Araujo(1991) The once but not twice differentiability of the Policy function](https://doi.org/10.2307/2938372) or this one [Santos (1991): Smoothness of the Policy function in discrete time models](https://doi.org/10.2307/2938371).